# iOS ScrollView w/contentView (UIView) doesn't display content (using Cirrious FluentLayouts)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm not very familiar with scroll views on iOS so please bear with me.  I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Preview.  I have a view on the main storyboard that has a banner at the top and a label under that.  I then put a scroll view under the label as I do not want the banner and label to scroll off the screen.  Then programmatically I add a UIView called `contentView` to the scroll view after adding two controls to the content view, a label called `lblUsername` and a text view called `txtUsername`, I set the text of the label to "Enter Username".  I only added these two things to the content view to keep things simple until I could better understand how this all works.  The code compiles with no errors, but when I run it on my test device, nothing appears other than the banner and the label I placed under that.  My code:

```
public partial class createAccount : UIViewController
{
    public User MyUser;
    public createAccount (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {

        viewCreateAccount.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        var height = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;

        UIView contentView = new UIView();
        UILabel lblUsername = new UILabel();
        UITextView txtUsername = new UITextView();
        lblUsername.Text = "Enter Username: ";
        contentView.AddSubviews(lblUsername);
        contentView.AddSubviews(txtUsername);

        viewCreateAccount.AddConstraints
        (

            banner.AtTopOf(View, height),
            banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
            banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),

            lblTitle.Below(banner, 0),
            lblTitle.WithSameWidth(banner)

        );

        scrollView.Add(contentView);
        scrollView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        scrollView.AddConstraints(contentView.FullWidthOf(scrollView));

        contentView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        contentView.AddConstraints(
            lblUsername.AtTopOf(contentView,0),
            lblUsername.AtLeftOf(contentView,0),

            txtUsername.ToRightOf(lblUsername,2)
        );
    }
}
```

What am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in Version `16.6.1` of VS , it seems that `UITextView` can not shows when using **Cirrious.FluentLayout** .Maybe it's an issue or limitation of *Cirrious.FluentLayout* , you can connect to author to reprot this .

If modify the `UITextView` to `UITextField` , then it will show .

```
...
UIView contentView = new UIView();
UILabel lblUsername = new UILabel();
UITextField txtUsername = new UITextField();
lblUsername.Text = "Enter Username: ";
contentView.AddSubviews(lblUsername);
contentView.AddSubviews(txtUsername);

txtUsername.Text = "Enter UITextField ";
txtUsername.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
txtUsername.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
...
```

The effect (*here add a background color for scollview*):

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what I was thinking, I wanted to use a `UITextField` all along, not `UITextView`.  Duh .... I've made significant changes to this particular screen and I think I'm at a point where I can now focus on whether or not this will scroll when I populate `contentView` with all the subviews I need to capture the data I need.  I now create `contentView` programmatically, but I have to calculate the placement and that I think is going to be problematic but that will be a different question or I'll go back to a fixed placement.  Dunno ... have to see what works best.

Comment: @PrescottChartier Glad it works for you . If occurs new question , you can create an new question to detail that . There will be more people to help you check that :-)

Comment: I wish things were easier ... lol ... now I have another problem, see the link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763327/ios-subviews-all-lumped-together-at-top-of-content-view-using-cirrious-fluentla ... perhaps you can help ...

Comment: @PrescottChartier Thanks for sharing , I will check that .