# iOS Subviews all lumped together at top of content view (using Cirrious FluentLayouts)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I'm not at all familiar with `UIScrollView` and content so please bear with me, I originally had an issue where things were not displayed at all and now they are all displayed at 0,0, except for `lblPassword` which is in the correct location below `lblUsername`.  I assumed that there was an `contentView` size issue, so I coded it with size parameters, etc, but nothing seems to work.  My code is:

```
public partial class createAccount : UIViewController
{
    public User MyUser;
    public createAccount (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {

        base.ViewDidLoad();
        viewCreateAccount.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        var height = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;

        nfloat bannerHeight = banner.Frame.Height;
        nfloat lblTitleHeight = lblTitle.Frame.Height;

        UIView contentView = new UIView();

        UILabel lblUsername = new UILabel();
        UITextField txtUsername = new UITextField();
        txtUsername.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
        lblUsername.Text = "Enter Username: ";
        txtUsername.Placeholder = "Enter Username";

        UILabel lblPassword = new UILabel();
        lblPassword.Text = "Enter Password:";

        UITextField txtPassword = new UITextField();
        txtPassword.Placeholder = "Enter Password";
        txtPassword.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblConfirmPassword = new UILabel();
        UITextField txtConfirmPassword = new UITextField();
        txtConfirmPassword.Placeholder = "Confirm Password";
        txtConfirmPassword.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblEmailAddress = new UILabel();
        UITextField txtEmailAddress = new UITextField();
        txtEmailAddress.Placeholder = "Enter Email Address";
        txtEmailAddress.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblConfirmEmailAddress = new UILabel();
        UITextField txtConfirmEmailAddress = new UITextField();
        txtConfirmEmailAddress.Placeholder = "Confirm Email Address";
        txtConfirmEmailAddress.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;


        contentView.Add(lblUsername);
        contentView.Add(txtUsername);

        contentView.Add(lblPassword);
        contentView.Add(txtPassword);
        contentView.Add(lblConfirmPassword);
        contentView.Add(txtConfirmPassword);
        contentView.Add(lblEmailAddress);
        contentView.Add(txtEmailAddress);
        contentView.Add(lblConfirmEmailAddress);
        contentView.Add(txtConfirmEmailAddress);


        contentView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        contentView.AddConstraints(
            lblUsername.AtTopOf(contentView, 0),
            lblUsername.AtLeftOf(contentView, 0),

            txtUsername.WithSameWidth(lblUsername),
            txtUsername.ToRightOf(lblUsername, 2),

            lblPassword.Below(txtUsername, 0),
            txtPassword.ToRightOf(lblPassword, 2),

            lblConfirmPassword.Below(lblPassword, 0),
            txtConfirmPassword.ToRightOf(lblConfirmPassword, 2),

            lblEmailAddress.Below(lblConfirmPassword, 0),
            txtEmailAddress.ToRightOf(lblEmailAddress, 2),

            lblConfirmEmailAddress.Below(lblEmailAddress, 0),
            txtConfirmEmailAddress.ToRightOf(lblConfirmEmailAddress, 2),

            txtEmailAddress.WithSameWidth(txtConfirmEmailAddress)
        );



        UIScrollView scrollView = new UIScrollView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, bannerHeight + lblTitleHeight + 75f, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height));
        scrollView.Add(contentView);
        viewCreateAccount.Add(scrollView);


        scrollView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        viewCreateAccount.AddConstraints
        (

            banner.AtTopOf(View, height),
            banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
            banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),

            lblTitle.Below(banner, 0),
            lblTitle.WithSameWidth(banner)

            ,scrollView.Below(lblTitle,0)
            ,contentView.WithSameWidth(scrollView)
            ,contentView.WithSameHeight(scrollView)
        );
     }
}
```

Nothing I do corrects the problem, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

From shared code , there are two things missing .

- One is forget to set Text for `UILabel` or `UITextField` , this will make part of them invisible .
- The another one is need to set `Below` margin for `UITextField` . If only setting `ToRightOf` , all the `UITextField` will override in the first row .

Therefore , code can be modified as follow :

```
...
        UIView contentView = new UIView();

        UILabel lblUsername = new UILabel();
        UITextField txtUsername = new UITextField();
        txtUsername.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
        lblUsername.Text = "Enter Username: ";
        txtUsername.Placeholder = "Enter Username";
        txtUsername.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

        UILabel lblPassword = new UILabel();
        lblPassword.Text = "Enter Password:";

        UITextField txtPassword = new UITextField();
        txtPassword.Placeholder = "Enter Password";
        txtPassword.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblConfirmPassword = new UILabel();
        lblConfirmPassword.Text = "Confirm Password";
        UITextField txtConfirmPassword = new UITextField();
        txtConfirmPassword.Placeholder = "Confirm Password";
        txtConfirmPassword.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblEmailAddress = new UILabel();
        lblEmailAddress.Text = "Enter Email Address";
        UITextField txtEmailAddress = new UITextField();
        txtEmailAddress.Placeholder = "Enter Email Address";
        txtEmailAddress.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblConfirmEmailAddress = new UILabel();
        lblConfirmEmailAddress.Text = "Confirm Email Address";
        UITextField txtConfirmEmailAddress = new UITextField();
        txtConfirmEmailAddress.Placeholder = "Confirm Email Address";
        txtConfirmEmailAddress.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;


        contentView.Add(lblUsername);
        contentView.Add(txtUsername);

        contentView.Add(lblPassword);
        contentView.Add(txtPassword);
        contentView.Add(lblConfirmPassword);
        contentView.Add(txtConfirmPassword);
        contentView.Add(lblEmailAddress);
        contentView.Add(txtEmailAddress);
        contentView.Add(lblConfirmEmailAddress);
        contentView.Add(txtConfirmEmailAddress);


        contentView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        contentView.AddConstraints(
            lblUsername.AtTopOf(contentView, 0),
            lblUsername.AtLeftOf(contentView, 0),

            txtUsername.WithSameWidth(lblUsername),
            txtUsername.Below(contentView, 0), // add below margin
            txtUsername.ToRightOf(lblUsername, 2),

            lblPassword.Below(txtUsername, 5),
            txtPassword.Below(txtUsername, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtPassword.ToRightOf(lblPassword, 2),

            lblConfirmPassword.Below(lblPassword, 5),
            txtConfirmPassword.Below(lblPassword, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtConfirmPassword.ToRightOf(lblConfirmPassword, 2),

            lblEmailAddress.Below(lblConfirmPassword, 5),
            txtEmailAddress.Below(lblConfirmPassword, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtEmailAddress.ToRightOf(lblEmailAddress, 2),

            lblConfirmEmailAddress.Below(lblEmailAddress, 5),
            txtConfirmEmailAddress.Below(lblEmailAddress, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtConfirmEmailAddress.ToRightOf(lblConfirmEmailAddress, 2),

            txtEmailAddress.WithSameWidth(txtConfirmEmailAddress)
        );
...
```

The effect :

[image]

**In addition** , the `UITextField` can not interactive with finger touch event , you need to custom a `UIView` and make its ***Touch Responder Event*** can deliver to its subviews .

For example , custom a **MyUIView** class :

```
public class MyUIView : UIView
{
    public override bool PointInside(CGPoint point, UIEvent uievent)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Used in shared code :

```
...
UIView contentView = new MyUIView();
...
```

Comment: Copied the code exactly as shown and all I get is the `lblUsername` with the text, "Enter Username: " and absolutely nothing else.  Al the other subviews are not displayed.

Comment: @PrescottChartier Okey , could you share the current shows with a screenshot ? I will check that . In addition, `viewCreateAccount` /`banner`/`lblTitle` doesn't exist in my local code , it should be defined from `storyboard`

Comment: As usual Apple make everything so damn difficult!  Just can't get the screenshot off my phone and onto my PC!  `viewCreateAccount` is the view controller for the create account view, the banner and label are the "header" that I do not want to scroll off the screen when I scroll, so I try to calculate where the bottom of the label is so I can then place the scroll view  below it.  I'm gonna have to re-think this though because I don't know if this will work for all devices.

Comment: @PrescottChartier Okey , if answer be helpful and later solve that , remember to vote it up when you have time :-) In addition, there is a way to remote iOS simulator from PC . This will help you get the screenshot of iOS simulator easily in PC . In Visual Studio , click **Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> iOS Settings -> check the option (Remote Simulator to Windows)** .https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VeCF.png

Comment: That box was already checked.  I don't use the simulator, it's waaayyyy too slow, I use a iPhone 6s as my test device.